# How to use bind variables in the ArangoDB AQL Editor in the web interface

Tags: arangodb

My workflow is to first write AQL queries in the AQL Editor (web interface), then when it's done move it into code. Sometimes move it back out from code to edit more on the queries. Real code one always use bound variables.

The trouble is that I need to constantly remove/add the bound variables when moving the query between the AQL Editor and my code (where it is just a string).

**So the question is, how can I use bound variables in the AQL Editor?**

PS: Version 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: the AQL editor in the web interface currently has no support for bind variables, so they can't be used there.

Comment: Thank you, may I suggest it as a future enhancement?

Comment: Already added a github issue - https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1563 If I missed out on something (or you want to get notifications on that bug), please add it to the comments over there.

Comment: bind values were added on Friday. You can explore the patch here: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/commit/45d153ca9173f6aed7e269882a1dd0dd26f2291d , https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/commit/3ae8eed4cb6b524066d671fd7ccd02562f302d2c

Comment: Feature will be included in 2.8.0.